# Get value and text and div content javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I have the following javascript code in my button

`$('#button-confirm').on('click', function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'index.php?route=payment/leasing_plans/confirm',
    cache: false,
      data:{
        egn: $('#input-payment-egn').val(), 
        months: $('input[name=months]:checked').parent().text()
      },
    beforeSend: function() {
      $('#button-confirm').button('loading');
    },
    complete: function() {
      $('#button-confirm').button('reset');
    },
    success: function() {
      location = '<?php echo $continue; ?>';
    }
  });
});`

I want to take the data from this div

```
<div id="uni18" class="leasecond">
<input type="text" style="border: none; background: repeat;" readonly />Разсрочено плащане с UNI Credit, вноски 18 x обща дължима сума:
```

And the text AND the value from the radio button

```
<div class="radio">
    <label><input type="radio" name="months" value="uni18"  />18 месеца x </label>
    </div>
```

How can achieve it?
Thank you!

Comment: Is the `input` inside the `div`? Would you kindly post the correct HTML code? This would help a lot.

Comment: Yes, its in div, i will edit the question now

Comment: Could you also clarify the very first code block you posted? It doesn't make sense out of context.

Comment: yes i will do it

Comment: Ah, now that makes sense. So you want to get text and value from selected radio button, right?

Answer (score 1):

I made it like this:

```
months: $('input[name=months]:checked').parent().text() + $('input[name=months]:checked').val()
```